# If you have a lock on an object, do you have a lock on all its methods?

Tags: java, synchronized

Say we have a object foo:

```
class Foo(){
  public synchronized void instanceMethod(){}
}

var foo = new Foo();
```

if I have a lock on foo:

```
synchronized(foo){
  foo.instanceMethod();
}
```

do I also have a lock on the `instanceMethod()` call? Another way of asking the question - if I have a lock on foo, can another thread call foo.instanceMethod() (simultaneously)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I have a lock on foo, can another thread call foo.instanceMethod()?

They can call it, but the call will wait until execution leaves your block `synchronized` on `foo`, because `instanceMethod` is `synchronized`. Declaring an instance method `synchronized` is roughly the same as putting its entire body in a block `synchronized` on `this`.

If `instanceMethod` *weren't* synchronized, then of course the call wouldn't wait.

Note, though, that the `synchronized` block you've shown is unnecessary:

```
synchronized(foo){       // <==== Unnecessary
  foo.instanceMethod();
}
```

Because `instanceMethod` is `synchronized`, that can just be:

```
foo.instanceMethod();
```

...unless there's something else in the block as well.

Comment: Right so if you have a lock on foo, nobody else can call any of its methods, if that method has the synchronized keyword, yeah

Comment: @MrCholo - Only **`synchronized`** methods.

Comment: That `synchronized(foo)` block would be causing the caller to wait too...

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
    public synchronized void a() { //Do something }
    public void b() {
        synchronized(this) { // Do something }
    }
    public void c() { // Do something }
}
```

Then:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.a();
foo.b();
synchronized(foo) { foo.c(); }
```

All the 3 methods are all pretty much equivalent in terms of synchronization.

There is no such thing as "locking" a method. Locking is done only on objects. Marking a method `synchronized` simply makes it lock the instance (or its class object for static method).

When you access a method on a locked object, the execution would be blocked as the thread fails to retrieve the *monitor* for the specified object - that is even before the method has been called. So `foo.a()` would be blocked when it is getting the `foo`.

#### Adding on...

I suddenly remembered something. If you have thread A calling `foo.a()` and it is taking a very long time to complete, and at that time another thread calls `foo.c()`, then `foo.c()` will still be blocked until `foo.a()` completes.