# Avoid synchronized block for boolean flip

Tags: java, concurrency

I have this method:

```
  public void lock(Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Unlock, Object> cb) {

    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.locked) {
        this.queue.add(cb);
        return;
      }

      this.locked = true;
    }

    cb.done(null, this.makeUnlock(true));

  }
```

is there some trick I can use to avoid the synchronized() call?

I believe assigning a boolean is atomic, so only one thread can do it at a time.

The idea is we want to avoid 2 threads acquiring the lock. We also don't want two different codepaths to acquire the lock, even if those are in the same thread.

Comment: Asyncc.IAsyncCallback, cb.done, this.makeUnlock - this is not standard java. Please add appropriate tag.

Comment: "we want to avoid 2 threads acquiring the lock" - besides the threads acquiring the lock, there must exist a thread which releases the lock, and which also may be the source of contention. Please show its code.

Comment: thats true, when the lock is released probably have a similar synchronization  issue as when the lock is acquired. its a similar problem, lets just focus on acquiring the lock since its the same concept

Comment: I am not sure what do you want, but it smells like you want implement syncronization mechanism like mutex or semaphore. If this is true, than it is much more than simple "flipping a boolean". `I believe assigning a boolean is atomic, so only one thread can do it at a time.` - It is near the truth (and using `AtomicBoolean`, as suggested by @Kuikiker, makes it really correct). But it is not clear, whether such replacent would be correct or not. E.g. `this.queue.add(cb);` can be called concurrently with `this.locked = true;` in other thread. We need to see more code and explanations.

Comment: Any inter-thread communication measure must be adhered by *all* threads accessing the shared resource. So a question showing only one part, like adding to a queue and setting a flag to true, omitting the other part(s), like taking the element from the queue and/or setting the flag to false, is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to potentially speed it up an iota, is to do something like:

```
  public void lock(Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<Unlock, Object> cb) {

    boolean add = false;
    synchronized (this) {
      if (this.locked) {
        add = true;
      }
      else {
        this.locked = true;
      }
    }

    if(add){
      this.queue.add(cb);
      return;
    }

    cb.done(null, this.makeUnlock(true));

  }
```

but I still don't know if there is a way to avoid the synchronized block.

Comment: this is wrong: 2 queues can interfere doing `this.queue.add(cb)` simultaneousely.

Comment: if I have a lock on `this`, it will lock on `this.queue` as well, tmk?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626010/if-you-have-a-lock-on-an-object-do-you-have-a-lock-on-all-its-methods

Comment: you wrote `this.queue.add(cb)` outside any synchronized statement or method, so the referenced question is irrelevant to your code.

Comment: yeah but the stack for each method call is unique, so the local variables will be independent of each other

Comment: `this.queue` refers to an object located in the heap, not a stack, and is accessible from different threads, so it must be protected with `synchronized` statement, but it is not.

Comment: That's right, but `add` is the local variable that determines access to the queue add.

Comment: so what? it does not provide exclusive access to the queue. Several threads can have `add=true` simultaneously and call `this.queue.add(cb)` at the same time, which may lead to data inconsistency.

Comment: they cant because access to the method and the local variables in it is synchronized

Comment: Let me break it down for you bro. the `add` variable is unique to the call stack. the `add` variable will only be set to `true` in the synchronized block.  Adding to the `this.queue` is dependent on the local variable assignment.  Dubai 1, Russia 0. :) That being said, adding to an array is fast (as opposed to shifting/unshifting an array).

Comment: fast, yes. This means, it will succesfully work for 1 year and only then crash.

Comment: it doesn’t matter whether `add` is set to `true` in the synchronized block, as `add` is a local variable anyway. It is never seen by other threads. All that matters, is that multiple threads can invoke `this.queue.add(cb);` concurrently. It doesn’t matter whether it’s fast, as in absence of synchronization, other threads can use inconsistent data even after hours. And well, when you already know it’s fast, why do you consider moving it out of the synchronized block could “potentially speed it up”? You just broke your code, not even answering your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the synchronized block can be avoided by using [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of boolean

Comment: See also a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155245/atomicboolean-vs-synchronized-block-whats-the-difference

Comment: can you show an example of how it make work given the code in the OP?